# Core Data does not update

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data, sdk

This is the sequence of steps I have taken:

- Load data into table view
- add new data
- click to see more details on cells
- load the details
- edit details
- press save
- back to table view
- everything is fine
- re-open the application
- nothing updated

I had this problem also with sqlite, and I didn't fix it. No, I am also stacked with CoreData.

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
    [passwords setValue:nametxt.text forKey:@"name"];

    [passwords setValue:usernametxt.text forKey:@"username"];


}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.title = passwords.name;

    nametxt.text = passwords.name;
    usernametxt.text = passwords.username;

}
```

Comment: How can anyone help you without seeing any code?

Comment: I think you need to call [passwords synchronize]; after your setValue: method calls.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `save` method of your `NSManagedObjectContext`.

```
NSError *error = nil;
[managedObjectContext save:&error];
if (error) {
//inform user
}
```

Comment: I am doing that
    NSError *error;
    
    if(![context save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }
but still nothing ...

Comment: How do you fetch/add your objects?

Comment: -(void) add:(id)sender
{
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [app managedObjectContext];    Passwords *passwords = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Passwords" inManagedObjectContext:context];
if(nametxt.text.length <=0 ||  usernametxt.text.length <= 0 || websitetxt.text.length <= 0 || passwordtxt.text.length <= 0)
{
NSLog(@"Empty");
}
else
{
passwords.name = nametxt.text;
passwords.username = usernametxt.text;
     
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    
    NSError *error;
    
    if(![context save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }
}